How To Build A Fat / Uber AAR From Multi Module Kotlin Multiplatform Library Project
I am fairly new to building Kotlin Multiplatform libraries, especially with a multi module setup. Recently I build a Kotlin Multiplatform library which has the following structure:
MyLibrary
│
├── :my-sdk
│
├── :my-sdk-api
│
├── :my-sdk-domain
│
└── :my-sdk-data

Each of these Gradle modules on its own is a Kotlin Multiplatform project with iOS and Android target. As an example the :my-sdk-api
my-sdk-api
│
├── :commonMain
│
├── :androidMain
│
└── :iOSMain

My goal is that the consumer just needs to include a dependency to the :my-sdk artifact like implementation("com.mydomain:my-sdk:1.0.0") and can work with the library via Factory class that the :my-sdk module provides. The consumer that only needs to know about the interfaces declared in the :my-sdk-api module.
Therefore the :my-sdk module includes the other Gradle modules as follows:
        commonMain.dependencies {
            api(project(":my-sdk-api"))
            implementation(project(":my-sdk-domain"))
            implementation(project(":my-sdk-data"))
            ..

When I now publish the :my-sdk to MavenLocal (m2) and consume the library in an Android app project, class references from the :my-sdk-api that the :my-sdk modules exposes can't be resolved..
From my understanding is that even if I declare my other Gradle projects, they won't be automatically build with the :my-sdk artefact and therefore even if I declare the :my-sdk-api module with api(project(":my-sdk-api")) it won't be included in the output .jar.
So TLDR;
How can I include all local Gradle modules that I need in my :my-sdk output artifact .aar so the user has everything he needs to work with my library? I already saw solutions like building a "fat jar" with the shadow plugin. But how to do that exactly for such a multi module kmp setup like mine and for an Android library (.aar) ?

Its better to use maven-publish plugin for your use case.

So you mean publishing all modules as separate artifacts?

Use the maven-publish plugin with publications configuration to create a publication that includes all required modules, and then publish this publication to your local Maven repository.

From my understanding that would be fine for local development but when I publish my library to maven central that would also require that I need to publish all modules as artifacts, right?

Basically there are 2 approaches to accomplish this task : 1. Use Gradle Shadow plugin to create a "fat AAR" by configuring it to merge all the dependent modules into a single artifact . 2. Use maven-publish plugin with appropriate configurations. While publishing the :my-sdk module as a single artifact to Maven Central is feasible, it's generally not recommended for maintainability and dependency management reasons. Conclusion its depends on you which you opt for after checking the pros and cons of both.

Thank you very much for your advice @Bob ! I appreciate that you took that time. After some reasoning I think I will go for your proposed solution with the maven-publish plugin.

Would you like to be posted as the answer with detailed explanation of maven-publish ?
